# Джетбрейнс выдает ошибку хотя все работает. React props методы

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, jetbrains

Проходил видео урок по теме контейнер компонентов, решил попрактиковаться.

Создал контейнерную компоненту которая возвращает вот такую компоненту[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите все свойства ( с ними проблем нет ) и методы переданы правильно.
Но IDE выдает следующую ошибку при попытке обратится к данным методам через пропсы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код работает идельно. В дебагере спокойно можно видеть данные методы в пропсах, но IDE почему то их не видит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20136714/2873538